# Creating an NSDate and setting AM or PM

Tags: swift, nsdate, nsdateformatter, nscalendar, nsdatecomponents

I have been trying to figure this out for the past 4 hours and can't seem to figure out how to solve this. A user comes in the app and selects a date on the calendar. The selected date is simply an `NSDate`. The user can then choose a time that consists of `hours`, `minutes`, and `seconds` and then they can select `AM` or `PM`.

So let's say the user chooses a time of `6:57 PM`. I need to modify the original `NSDate` that was created when they selected a date on the calendar, and change it's time data to match the `6:57 PM` time that the user just set.

I have been using the `dateBySettingHour` function of the `NSCalendar` class and it works great. The only problem is I cannot modify the `AM/PM` value. All I can do is pass it the hours, minutes, and seconds. Here's the code:

```
calendar.dateBySettingHour(hours, minute: minutes, second: seconds, ofDate: selectedDate, options: NSCalendarOptions())
```

I have been playing around with `NSDateFormatter`, `NSDateComponents`, and `NSCalendar` and been going through examples on here but I just can't seem to wrap my head around this and figure it out.

What would be the easiest and most efficient way for me to create a final date in `ISO 8601` date format that has the correct month, day, and year info as the original `NSDate`, but that now also has the correct time information including the `AM/PM` setting that the user has chosen?

I understand that this is impossible trying to use the `dateBySettingHour`, but I'm open to trying anything at this point.

Comment: How does the user pick the time? With a `UIDatePicker`? Or some other way?

Comment: Why don't you just add 12 to hours when user selects PM?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Xcode 8.3.2 • Swift 3.1**

```
let date = Date()
let hour = 6
let minute = 57
let second = 0
let pm = true

let hours24 = hour == 12 &&  pm ?   12 :
              hour == 12 && !pm ?    0 :
                            !pm ? hour : hour + 12

let dateWithHour = Calendar.current.date(bySettingHour: hours24, minute: minute, second: second, of: date)   // Jun 4, 2017, 6:57 PM"
```

Comment: Wow, time to get some sleep and step away from the monitor I guess

Answer (score 1):

Can you pass in "hours + 12" for PM?

Comment: Although short and stated as a question, this answer clearly **does** offer user3344977 a solution to his problem—the same solution, essentially, as in the accepted answer (which was posted one minute later than this answer).